# Cuda number of elements is larger than assigned threads

Tags: c++, cuda

I am new to CUDA programming.
I am curious that what happens if the number of elements is larger than the number of threads?

In this simple vector_add example

```
__global__
void add(int n, float *x, float *y)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i < n) 
        y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}
```

Say the number of array elements is 10,000,000. And we call this function using 64 blocks and 256 threads per block:

```
int n = 1e8;
int grid_size = 64;
int block_sie = 256;
```

Then, only 64*256 = 16384 threads are assigned, what would happen to the rest of the array elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what would happen to the rest of the array elements?

Nothing at all.  They wouldn't be touched and would remain unchanged.  Of course, your `x` array elements don't change anyway.  So we are referring to `y` here.  The values of `y[0..16383]` would reflect the result of the vector add.  The values of `y[16384..9999999]` would be unchanged.

For this reason (to conveniently handle arbitrary data set sizes independent of the chosen grid size), people sometimes suggest a [grid-stride-loop](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/) kernel design.

Comment: What will happen if we assign fewer number of threads in a vector of size N? Should the number of threads be the same as number of elements?